# Fixed Point Binary to LCD

Tags: c, binary, embedded, microcontroller, fixed

I'm so close to having output on my LCD as desired.  Problem is that when I extract the digits from the integer to have digits as integer and the remainder to be my fraction , I can't seem to get the right output.

Before the decimal the output looks fine but after, it doesn't.

```
void ST7735_uBinOut8(uint32_t n){
      uint32_t value2;

    value2 = n;

    char integer2[2];
    char fraction2[4];
    uint32_t f_part2 = abs(value2)%256;
    uint32_t i_part2 = ((abs(value2)) /256) ;

    if (abs(value2) > 256000U)
    {
        integer2[0] = '*';
              integer2[1] = '*';

            fraction2[0] = '*';
            fraction2[1] = '*';
            fraction2[2] = '*';
            fraction2[3] = '*';

     }
     else
     {
       if (abs(value2) < 256000U)
       sprintf(integer2, "%d", i_part2);
       sprintf(fraction2, "%.3d", f_part2); 
       }
    printf("%s.%s", integer2, fraction2);
```

The following are the values I pass to this function:

```
outTestCaseType2 outTests2[14]={ 
{     0,  " =   0.00?\r" }, //      0/256 = 0.00  
{     4,  " =   0.01?\r" }, //      4/256 = 0.01  
{    10,  " =   0.03?\r" }, //     10/256 = 0.03
{   200,  " =   0.78?\r" }, //    200/256 = 0.78
{   254,  " =   0.99?\r" }, //    254/256 = 0.99
{   505,  " =   1.97?\r" }, //    505/256 = 1.97
{  1070,  " =   4.17?\r" }, //   1070/256 = 4.17
{  5120,  " =  20.00?\r" }, //   5120/256 = 20.00
{ 12184,  " =  47.59?\r" }, //  12184/256 = 47.59
{ 26000,  " = 101.56?\r" }, //  26000/256 = 101.56
{ 32767,  " = 127.99?\r" }, //  32767/256 = 127.99
{ 34567,  " = 135.02?\r" }, //  34567/256 = 135.02
{255998,  " = 999.99?\r" }, // 255998/256 = 999.99
{256000,  " = ***.**?\r" }  // error
};
```

Below is a screen shot of my output and the column on my right is what I'm supposed to get.
[OUTPUT IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS0TC.png)

Comment: Think what the modulo operator does and why that causes your problem.

Comment: `sprintf` will attempt to create null-terminated strings, but you aren't using null terminators, nor are you allocating space for them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by playing around with the operators.  I changed to as follows and it seems to work and get the output I wanted after like 4 h but I'm sure that 4 h goes towards me learning and that's the struggle of a noob but its ok.

```
void ST7735_uBinOut8(uint32_t n){
      uint32_t value2;

    value2 = (n*1000)/256;

    char integer2[2];
    char fraction2[4];
    uint32_t f_part2 = abs(value2)%1000;
    uint32_t i_part2 = ((abs(value2)) /1000) ;

    //f_part2 = abs(f_part2)%1000;
   // i_part2 = abs(i_part2) /1000 ;

    if (abs(n) >= 256000U)
    {
        integer2[0] = '*';
              integer2[1] = '*';

            fraction2[0] = '*';
            fraction2[1] = '*';
            fraction2[2] = '*';
            fraction2[3] = '*';

     }
     else
     {
       if (abs(n) < 256000U)
       sprintf(integer2, "%d", i_part2);
       sprintf(fraction2, "%.3d", (f_part2)); 
       }
    printf("%s.%.2s", integer2, fraction2);

}
```

This is my output now: [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ4xy.png)